# why is the next line not displaying on click (love2d)?

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

I'm trying to make a code where there is a dialogue, e.g. line1, line2, line3, and per click it will go to the next line / next line will display.

But when I click nothing triggers. I also have a feature where it displays the text letters one by one, and on click, will display all the characters in that line on click if everything is not already displayed, before you move onto the next line-- which is also not working.

here is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
--[[
local dialoguePage = {}
local currentScreen = startScreen

function dialoguePage.load()
end

function dialoguePage.update(dt)
end

function dialoguePage.draw()
end

function dialoguePage.load()
    textToDisplay = {
        "Ah!?", 
        "I'm in trouble, in trouble..", 
        "I need to feed teru, but I'm so behind on my music work right now...",     
        "would you be kind enough to help me feed teru for me?!", 
        "Thank you very much!"
    }
    currentLine = 1
    numberOfCharsToDisplay = 0
    timePassed = 0
    timeForEachChar = 0.25
end

function dialoguePage.update(dt)
    timePassed = timePassed + dt
    if timePassed >= timeForEachChar then
         timePassed = timePassed - timeForEachChar
         numberOfCharsToDisplay = numberOfCharsToDisplay + 1
         
    end
    love.mousepressed(x, y, button)

end

function dialoguePage.draw()
    love.graphics.print(textToDisplay[currentLine]:sub(1, numberOfCharsToDisplay), 0, 0)
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if button == 1 then
        if numberOfCharsToDisplay < #textToDisplay[currentLine] then
            -- If there are more characters to display, show them
            numberOfCharsToDisplay = #textToDisplay[currentLine]
        else
            -- Otherwise, move to the next line of text
            currentLine = currentLine + 1
            if currentLine > #textToDisplay then
                -- If we've reached the end of the text, loop back to the beginning
                currentLine = 1
            end
            numberOfCharsToDisplay = 0
        end
    end
end
]]

local dialoguePage = {}
local currentScreen = startScreen
local requestPage = require("requestPage")

textToDisplay = {
    "Ah!?", 
    "I'm in trouble, in trouble..", 
    "I need to feed teru, but I'm so behind on my music work right now...",     
    "would you be kind enough to help me feed teru for me?!", 
    "Thank you very much!"
}
currentLine = 1
numberOfCharsToDisplay = 0
timePassed = 0
timeForEachChar = 0.25

function dialoguePage.load()
end

function dialoguePage.update(dt)
    timePassed = timePassed + dt
    if timePassed >= timeForEachChar then
         timePassed = timePassed - timeForEachChar
         numberOfCharsToDisplay = numberOfCharsToDisplay + 1
    end
end

function dialoguePage.draw()
    love.graphics.print(textToDisplay[currentLine]:sub(1, numberOfCharsToDisplay), 0, 0)
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if button == 1 then
        if numberOfCharsToDisplay >= #textToDisplay[currentLine] then
            -- If there are no more characters to display, move to the next line of text
            currentLine = currentLine + 1
            if currentLine > #textToDisplay then
                -- If reached the end of the text, go to the next screen
                currentScreen = requestPage
                requestPage.load()
            end
            numberOfCharsToDisplay = 0
        else
            -- Otherwise, show all the remaining characters on the current line
            numberOfCharsToDisplay = #textToDisplay[currentLine]
        end
    end
end

return dialoguePage
```

Answer (score 1):

`love.mousepressed()` is one of the callback functions of the framework. You define it, and then love2d calls it as soon as one of the buttons on the mouse is pressed and hands over x,y and the button (1 or 2) as arguments. This might not solve your problem, but you should never call the function yourself, which you did inside of `dialoguePage.update`. I see this is part of the commented code, but still worthy to point out. When you end your comment you terminate with `]]` maybe change that to `--]]`. (According to the Lua documentation, this is how you define multiline comments.)

I think you renamed the love callback functions because you want to use it as a module. I never did it like this, but if you find a way to make it work, then shouldn't `love.mousepressed()` also be `dialoguePage.mousepressed()`?

Another way to find the bug would be to make a simple `print()` statement inside of the `mousepressed` function to see if it's being called.

Comment: yup, that fixed the problem! I am new to love2d so I missed that mistake...